# Function for creating relative frequency tables for each variable

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have a dataset with 220 variables (columns). My data look like this

```
    test      var1   var2      var3
1   Pretest   No    Sometimes   No
2   Postest   No    Sometimes   No
3   Pretest   No    Yes         No
4   Postest   No    Yes         No
5   Pretest   No    Sometimes   No
6   Postest   No    Yes         No
7   Pretest   No    Yes         No
8   Postest   No    No          No
9   Pretest   No    Yes         No
10  Postest   No    Sometimes   No
11  Pretest   No    Sometimes   No
12  Postest   No    No  No
13  Pretest   Yes   Yes No
14  Postest   No    Sometimes   No
15  Pretest   No    No  No
16  Postest   No    Sometimes   No
17  Pretest   No    Sometimes   No
18  Postest   No    No  No
19  Pretest   No    Yes No
20  Postest   No    Yes No
```

For **each** variable I want to produce a relative frequency table by group. To that end, I'm using dplyr

```
propvar1 <- dataprepost %>% 
  group_by(test,var1) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(rel.freq = paste0(round(100 * n/sum(n), 0), "%"))
```

For instance, this gives me the table I want for Var1:

```
    test      var1      n     rel.freq
1   Postest   Sometimes 120   14%
2   Postest   No        667   79%
3   Postest   Yes       44    5%
4   Postest   NA        10    1%
5   Pretest   Sometimes 155   18%
6   Pretest   No        623   74%
7   Pretest   Yes       49    6%
8   Pretest   NA        14    2%
```

How can I create a function to do this automatically for each variable in the data set, so I end up with a similar table for each variable?

Comment: Please make your example reproducible by including sample data and matching expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most elegant piece of code... But it works!

## Data

```
d <- structure(list(test = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                       1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Postest", 
                                                                                                       "Pretest"), class = "factor"), var1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                         1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                         1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), var2 = structure(c(2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("No", "Sometimes", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
                    var3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "No", class = "factor")), .Names = c("test", 
                                                                                                                              "var1", "var2", "var3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
                                                                                                                                                                                           "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
                                                                                                                                                                                           "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"))`
```

## Solution

```
output <- NULL

for (t_cat in unique(d$test)) {
  x <- d[d$test == t_cat, ]
  x$test <- NULL

  l <- lapply(x, function(x) {
    output <- data.frame(table(x))
    colnames(output) <- c('val', 'n')
    output$rel.freq <- output$n/length(x)
    output$category <- t_cat
    return(output)
  })

  r <- do.call("rbind", lapply(names(l), function(x) { cbind(l[[x]], 'var' = x)}))

  output <- rbind(output, r)
}

print(output)

# val  n rel.freq category  var
# 1         No  9      0.9  Pretest var1
# 2        Yes  1      0.1  Pretest var1
# 3         No  1      0.1  Pretest var2
# 4  Sometimes  4      0.4  Pretest var2
# 5        Yes  5      0.5  Pretest var2
# 6         No 10      1.0  Pretest var3
# 7         No 10      1.0  Postest var1
# 8        Yes  0      0.0  Postest var1
# 9         No  3      0.3  Postest var2
# 10 Sometimes  4      0.4  Postest var2
# 11       Yes  3      0.3  Postest var2
# 12        No 10      1.0  Postest var3
```

Comment: Thanks. The function should group by test and variable, then calculate n, and then calculate the relative frecuency of each variable. This function seems to work only with one variable.

Comment: Fixed answer, see above!

Comment: Thank you very much @12b345b6b78 This is exactly what I wanted to do. But just one more thing: How can I change the function If I wanted to group by more than one variable, for instance, 'test' and 'school'?

Comment: Unfortunately, the only suggestion I have is to keep wrapping it in for loops (looping through unique values in 'test', 'school' etc), while not forgetting to alter the innermost subset `d[d$test == t_cat, ]` such that it represents a slice of original data that only has the specific 'test', 'school', etc inherited from the loops